# Control browser scrollbar height

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, webkit

I noticed that when I have an element with a horizontal scrollbar, Chrome will add a scrollbar within the element without changing the height, but Firefox will increase the element height to make room for the scrollbar. Any way to control this behavior in either case?

Comment: The effect of the Chrome scrollbar should be seen as just a fancy bonus. If you were to turn on scrollbars in Chrome, instead of how it just detects when hovered ~ I believe that it will also change the height as firefox does. There isn't really any way to tell it what to do. : /